# how many times 5 fits in to a set number

Tags: php, math

I've written some basic messy code to solve this issue but I'm sure there must be a much better way of doing it. Here's my attempt:

```
$max = 17.9;
$box=0;
$x=0;
for (;;) {
   if ($box > $max) break;
   $box+=5;
   $x++;
}
$bonus = $x-1;
echo "$bonus points added!";
```

So here we see that 5 fit's in to 17.9 3 times.

Comment: `$max = 20.9;`
`echo floor($max / 5);`
new attemp, lot smaller :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made this way harder then it needed to be

```
$bonus = intval(17 / 5);
```

1. Divide 17 by 5
2. Remove the remainder (`floor()` works here as well)

Comment: In fairness to the OP, code is "way harder than it needs to be" when one is unfamiliar with functions that wrap it all up into a simple block. That's one reason people come to this site. Nice answer.

Comment: simple math.. it just didnt come to mind until i posted.. bummer. it's always interesting to see multiple ways of doing something to get the same result :) thanks

Comment: Sometimes you have to talk it out for the solution to become obvious. I've started writing several question here only to have the solution come to be as I was writing my question. :)